# .each () issue with AJAX function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that displays blocks . They are 4 colums and 4 rows, a total of 16 blocks .
However, when you reach the bottom of the page a have an AJAX function that loads 16 more blocks every time you reach the bottom of the page.

I want an animation on load for these blocks ( I change opacity from 0 to 1), to do this I add a class to these elements gradually with this code:

For column 1:
(`.colnum1` corresponds to a block in column 1)

```
$('.colnum1').each(function(u){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.colnum1').eq(u).addClass('selected');
  }, 1200 * u);
});
```

For column 2:
(`.colnum2` corresponds to a block in column 2)

```
$('.colnum2').each(function(z){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.colnum2').eq(z).addClass('selected');
  }, 300 + 1200 * z);
});
```

And this all works Great for the first 16 elements.

However, when I load the next 16 elements, they is a delay before they appear (before the animation `onload` occurs).
I have figured out what this delay corresponds to ...
When I reach the bottom of the page and the jQuery `.each()` functions are executed again, they go throw the already existing elements before the new elements... Which makes sense but not is not wanted.

I have tried to rewrite the functions so that it doesn't go threw the already 'loaded' elements first .

With this code: (`.selected` being the class that add the `onload` animation)

```
$('.colnum1:not(.selected)').each(function(u){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.colnum1:not(.selected)').eq(u).addClass('selected');
  }, 1200 * u);
});
```

But for some reason, it isn't adding the class `.selected` to all the elements... It skips some etc.

So I would like to know How can I make sure that when I get the new 16 elements the `.each` function doesn't go throw all of the previous existing elements first (causing a long wait time)?

Comment: Why are you using a setTimeout? Why are you using .each?

Comment: @KevinB So that not all 16 elements appear at the same time, so that they is a nice looking flow

Comment: wait, so, you're loading all of the content, only showing a small portion of it, then showing more as the user scrolls but forcing them to wait on your animation to display them? thats.... not cool.

Comment: Sites don't use that kind of functionality to get a smooth flow, they use it to cause the initial page load to be faster by not loading all of the content up front. You're loading all the content up front, thus making it pointless to not just go ahead and show it all.

Comment: I think you've just poorly explained your problem. The code snippets you've provided don't make sense on a page that is loading more content with ajax when scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: @KevinB No Not all of the content is loaded at the start, its loads progressively with the ajax function in order to have faster page.
The animation onload is just a quick cool looking addition.

Comment: @KevinB I realize but all the code is complex, i tried to simplify it to keep relevant information to fix problem

Answer (score 0):

The reason it failed to select all the elements was that it was re-evaluating the term `$('.colnum1:not(.selected)')` each time it called the handler.

Let's go through this step by step. We'll only pay attention to the first column.

First it evaluates `$('.colnum1:not(.selected)')`, which contains all 4 blocks in the first column. Then it iterates over these blocks and calls `setTimeout` 4 times. So far so good.

Then it calls the handler for the first time. It evaluates `$('.colnum1:not(.selected)')` again, and the jQuery object again consists of all 4 blocks. It chooses the first of these (because `u=0`) and adds the `selected` class to it.

1200 milliseconds later, it calls the handler again. But this time round, **the jQuery object `$('.colnum1:not(.selected)')` is different**. It no longer contains the first block, because of the `.selected` filter. And `u=1` now, so `$('.colnum1:not(.selected)').eq(u)` is the second element of this new, shortened list, i.e. the third block in the column. Obviously, you wanted the second one.

There are several ways to fix this:

- You could change `.eq(u)` to `.eq(0)`. I don't like this very much.
- You could save `$('.colnum1:not(.selected)')` to a variable before the loop, then use the variable inside the handler instead of evaluating the CSS selector again. The jQuery object would continue to represent the same 4 elements, even when they no longer match the selector.
- The `.each` handler receives the current HTML element as an argument. Not as a jQuery object, but as a raw DOM element. But you can make it a jQuery object by calling `$`, then use the new jQuery object. Like so: 
  `$('.colnum1').each(function(u, block){
  setTimeout(function(){
  $(block).addClass('selected');
  }, 1200 * u);
  });`
- Or as a minor variant to the previous approach, the handler also receives the DOM element through the `this` keyword. So instead of having the `block` argument you'd write `var block = this;` just before `setTimeout`. (Simply replacing `$(block)` with `$(this)` may not work - I'm not sure what the value of `this` is inside a `setTimeout` handler. It may even be browser-dependent for all I know.)